# Increase the maximum number of open file descriptors in Snow Leopard?

Tags: mac, osx-snow-leopard, ulimit, file-descriptors

I am trying to do something that requires a large number of file descriptors

`sudo ulimit -n 12288` is as high as Snow Leopard wants to go; beyond this results in

> /usr/bin/ulimit: line 4: ulimit: open files: cannot modify limit: Invalid argument.

I want to raise the number much higher, say 100000. Is it possible?

Comment: This question's answers no longer work in OSX Mavericks.

Comment: Running `echo limit maxfiles 10000 10000|sudo tee -a /etc/launchd.conf` and restarting works for me in Mavericks.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

Using `ulimit` command only changes the resource limits for the current shell and its children and `sudo ulimit` creates a root shell, adjusts its limits, and then exits (thus having, as far as I can see, no real effect).
To exceed 12288, you need to adjust the kernel's `kern.maxfiles` and `kern.maxfilesperproc` parameters, and also (at least according to [this blog entry](http://artur.hefczyc.net/node/27), which is a summary of [this discussion](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1449787)) a launchd limit. You can use `launchctl limit` to adjust all of these at once:

```
sudo launchctl limit maxfiles 1000000 1000000
```

To make this permanent (i.e not reset when you reboot), create `/etc/launchd.conf` containing:

```
limit maxfiles 1000000 1000000
```

*Then* you can use `ulimit` (but without the `sudo`) to adjust your process limit.

If this doesn't do it, you may be running into size limits in the kernel.  If [your model supports it](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3770), booting the kernel in [64-bit mode](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3773) may help.

Comment: `sudo launchctl limit maxfiles 1000000 unlimited`
Neither the hard nor soft limit for "maxfiles" can be unlimited. Please use a numeric parameter for both.

Comment: Be careful when adding that line to `launchd.conf`. I think if the number is too small, it can make your computer unusable. For example, I used `limit maxfiles 1024 1024` and I had a really hard time changing it back.

Comment: Alas: "The /etc/launchd.conf file is no longer consulted for subcommands to run during early boot time; this functionality was removed for security considerations."

Comment: It does not work, my fd number can not exceed 6k even if I set ulimit -Sn 10240 successfully.

Comment: @JianWeihang fd numbers are per-process so I assume other processes happened to have 4000 files open. Do you happen to run Chrome? ;)

Answer (score 42):

The following should resolve most solutions (and are listed in order of their hierarchy):

```
echo 'kern.maxfiles=20480' | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf
echo -e 'limit maxfiles 8192 20480\nlimit maxproc 1000 2000' | sudo tee -a /etc/launchd.conf
echo 'ulimit -n 4096' | sudo tee -a /etc/profile
```

Notes:

1. You will need to restart for these changes to take effect.
2. AFAIK you can no longer set limits to 'unlimited' under OS X
3. launchctl maxfiles are bounded by sysctl maxfiles, and
   therefore cannot exceed them
4. sysctl seems to inherit kern.maxfilesperproc from launchctl
   maxfiles
5. ulimit seems to inherit it's 'open files' value from
   launchctl by default
6. you can set a custom ulimit within /etc/profile, or
   ~/.profile ; while this isn't required I've provided an example
7. Be cautious when setting any of these values to a very high number when compared with their default - the features exist stability/security.  I've taken these example numbers that I believe to be reasonable, written on other websites.

Comment: Alas: "The /etc/launchd.conf file is no longer consulted for subcommands to run during early boot time; this functionality was removed for security considerations."

Answer (score 39):

It seems like there is an entirely different method for changing the open files limit for each version of OS X!

**For OS X Sierra** (10.12.X) you need to:

1.
In `Library/LaunchDaemons` create a file named `limit.maxfiles.plist` and paste the following in (feel free to change the two numbers (which are the soft and hard limits, respectively):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN"  
        "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">  
  <dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>limit.maxfiles</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
      <string>launchctl</string>
      <string>limit</string>
      <string>maxfiles</string>
      <string>64000</string>
      <string>524288</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>ServiceIPC</key>
    <false/>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

2.
Change the owner of your new file:

```
sudo chown root:wheel /Library/LaunchDaemons/limit.maxfiles.plist
```

3. 
Load these new settings:

```
sudo launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/limit.maxfiles.plist
```

4.
Finally, check that the limits are correct:

```
launchctl limit maxfiles
```

Comment: This answer is great, and I found some background to add to it here, @ninjaPixel: http://blog.dekstroza.io/ulimit-shenanigans-on-osx-el-capitan/

Answer (score 21):

It seems that OS X Lion will not permit "unlimited" as a value:

```
% sudo launchctl limit maxfiles 8192 unlimited
Neither the hard nor soft limit for "maxfiles" can be unlimited. Please use a numeric parameter for both.
```

Providing numerical values for both the soft and the hard limit does the job:

```
% sudo launchctl limit maxfiles 4096 8192
```

Comment: If one of the values was *unlimited*, using `-1` as value results in `12288`. It's possible to use larger numeric values, e.g. `sudo launchctl limit maxfiles 15000 150000`. I'm not sure these settings have an effect then, though.

Answer (score 10):

On Mavericks its simple.  As a regular user:

`ulimit -n 8192`

You can check the updated settings via

`ulimit -a`

On my machine:

```
ulimit -a
-t: cpu time (seconds)              unlimited
-f: file size (blocks)              unlimited
-d: data seg size (kbytes)          unlimited
-s: stack size (kbytes)             8192
-c: core file size (blocks)         0
-v: address space (kbytes)          unlimited
-l: locked-in-memory size (kbytes)  unlimited
-u: processes                       709
-n: file descriptors                8192
```

Comment: Consider revising your solution. You're setting a ulimit of 1024, then showing the output file descriptors as 8192 (should be 1024). You're approach is also probelmatic without sudo, try changing it a few times for yourself.

Comment: sudo should not be used here but this answer is incorrect. Mavericks users should use ```echo limit maxfiles 10000 10000|sudo tee -a /etc/launchd.conf``` and then restart their machine

Answer (score 4):

On **OS X 10.13.6** this works for me:

```
$ sysctl kern.maxfiles
kern.maxfiles: 12288
$ sysctl kern.maxfilesperproc
kern.maxfilesperproc: 10240
$ sudo sysctl -w kern.maxfiles=1048600
kern.maxfiles: 12288 -> 1048600
$ sudo sysctl -w kern.maxfilesperproc=1048576
kern.maxfilesperproc: 10240 -> 1048576
$ ulimit -S -n
256
$ ulimit -S -n 1048576
$ ulimit -S -n
1048576
```

Answer (score 2):

Some limits cannot be changed by `ulimit`, because they only apply to the current shell, therefore `launchctl` command should be used to change the limits globally, e.g.

```
sudo launchctl limit maxfiles 100000 unlimited
```

Please note that applying these limits in `/etc/launchd.conf` (as suggested in other answers) is no longer supported in the recent macOS releases. Although can still use `launchd.plist` (see: `man launchd.plist`) such as per-user or system-wide `plist` configuration files as suggested [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/293062/21471), [there](https://superuser.com/a/1171023/87805), and over [there](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/221988/21471).

---

To make these limits persistent, you can use `/etc/sysctl.conf` file and add for example:

```
kern.maxprocperuid=1000
kern.maxproc=2000
kern.maxfilesperproc=20000
kern.maxfiles=50000
```

<sup>For changes to take the effect, it requires reboot.</sup>

To see the current limits, run: `launchctl limit` or `sysctl -a | grep ^kern.max`.

See also: [How to persist ulimit settings in macOS?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/108174/21471)