# Permanently increase the maximum number of open file descriptors in launchctl on Mac OS X Mojave

Tags: mac, macos-mojave

I've found numerous links for how to permanently increase the maximum number of open file descriptors in previous verions of Mac OS X, but I have yet to get it to work on Mojave. For instance: [Increase the maximum number of open file descriptors in Snow Leopard?](https://superuser.com/questions/302754/increase-the-maximum-number-of-open-file-descriptors-in-snow-leopard)

Is there any way of permanently doing so now? I've already tried writing to `/etc/launchd.conf`, but I still get:

```
# launchctl limit maxfiles
maxfiles 256 0
```